# Extract indices of specified elements in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list. Each element is a real-value integer, and I want to extract the indices of specified element. For example:

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.where(A==1) #A is a list of [1,1,2,3,4,5....]
```

But `np.where` seems not to work for a list.

My next task is to obtain a new list from another list, `B`, based on the obtained indices:

```
C = B[idx]
```

Comment: Are you going to do something with those indices, otherwise isn't your new list going to be *n* many occurrences of `1`? So it might as well be `B = [1] * A.count(1)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the list `A` to an [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) and it should work

```
idx = np.where(np.array(A)==1)
C = [B[i] for i in idx[0]]
```

Comment: @np.where gives a tuple, but how to check many elements that have been extracted.

Comment: `A` is a 1d array. The indices you're looking for are in `idx[0]`

Comment: That is good, but idx[0] is an array. It is still not convenient to get a new list by directly using C=B[idx[0]]

Comment: That is the best I want!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `numpy` IMO. You can create B simply by using something like:

`B = [ele for ele in A if ele == 1]`

Comment: Thanks! but what if I still need those the same indices to deal with another list?

Comment: This will perform the filtering *in Python*. Usually Python is not very efficient when processing data in batch.

Comment: @jingweimo then you can have a separate list of indices with `indices = [i for i in range(len(A)) if A[i] == 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is a vanilla list (a default list in Python), then Python will interpret:

```
A == 1
```

as checking whether the **`list`** is equal to `1`. Which is of course not true.

You should turn `A` into an array:

```
Aa = np.array(A)        # construct a numpy array
idx = np.where(Aa == 1) # obtain the indices
B = Aa[idx]             # make a copy (again on the numpy array)
```